# Undefined variable Error in the script

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I could not access the required variable in the block as shown. I don't understand why.

```
define("appkit/controllers/me", ["appkit/utils/uploader", "exports"],
    function (__dependency1__, __exports__) {
        "use strict";
        var Uploader = __dependency1__["default"];
        var MeController;
        MeController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
            username: null,
            actions: {
                uploadProfilePic: function ($el) {
                    /*
                     * PROBLEM:
                     * 
                     * I dont understand why variable `Uploader` is not accessible over here.
                     * Could some one please explain?
                     * 
                     */
                     uploader = new Uploader(); // This line says "ReferenceError: Uploader is not defined".
                }
            }
        });

        __exports__["default"] = MeController;;
    }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Could some one please explain why?

Comment: This is how function scope works.Your inner function extend cannot access the variable uploader because of the scoping rules defined in javascript.https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a variable `Uploader` declared, but then you're trying to instantiate an instance of it as if it were a class.

Comment: It extends Ember.Object. It is supposed to act like a class.